# Drupal: Broken styles on admin pages

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-8

After running `drush cr` to clear the cache, all of the CSS styles have disappeared when accessing pages under `/admin/`. This includes pages in a custom module but also the default administration pages like `/admin/appearance`

When I examine the page source for any page the style sheet links are all empty:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/" />`

It seems like other people have had this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu/issues/1064128), but no fix has been found.

What's going on? How can I fix my admin styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that this is a permissions problem. Drupal prompts you to change the permissions for the `sites/default/files` directory to allow the system to cache files.

[image: File system. Writable (public download method). The directory sites/default/files is not writable. You may need to set the correct directory at the file system settings page or change the current directory's permissions so that it is writable.]

If you use `chown www-data sites/default/files` the message will disappear but Drupal still won't be able to write to the cache correctly because the files *in* that folder aren't owned by the web server.

You need to grant write permissions to all the contents of that folder too. The easiest way is `chown -R www-data sites/default/files` but Drupal has an extensive [guide to file permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) you may want to read.